# Is adding the logic for a event in a separated method to the one that triggers it a good practice?

Tags: c#, refactoring

For example let's say I have a windows form with some textboxes for numbers and a button, and when I click on the button I want to take the value of all of those texts and do some math with them.

Would this:

```
private void btnSomeResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    DoSomeMath();

}
```

be a better practice than say:

```
private void btnSomeResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    //Complex math goes here.

}
```

or does it depend on the complexity of the operation? For example it may not be needed in a simple multiplication, division etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void btnSomeResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

DoSomeMath();
```

}

This approach would be better suited because of following reasons

1. If your UI changes, like replacing a button with another another button which also need to do the same function, then you can reuse the functionality already written. In essence, your UI would be independent of the functionality of the button control.
2. You can Test the method (DoSomeMath) easily if you start with unit testing.

A still better way is to get the data from UI elements and pass it on to the method parameters in a more specific class/Type to ensure data is independent of UI Controls

```
   // This function reads the data from UI and call the next method which is more narrow in it's parameter type (like accepting params of type int )
    private void DoSomeMath()
    {
        // no error handling, just for demostration
        string firstNumber = int.Parse(txtBoxFirstNumer.Text);
        string secondNumber = int.Parse(txtBoxSecond.Text);

        DoSomeMath(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    // No relation to UI as it's parameter are independent of UI controls 
    private void DoSomeMath(string firstNumber, string secondNumber)
    {
        return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
```

Next, you can move the method `DoSomeMath(string firstNumber, string secondNumber)` to a different Class/Library so that it can be reused across different Windows Forms/Web pages/ or other classes.

Comment: This is what I thought but I wanted a second opinion, reutilization of code and test driven development seems like pretty good reasons to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally separate the code for your `complex math` if it is going to be reused or called from multiple places. (E.g. if you need to call it from multiple different button click handlers).

If not, there's no reason *not* to put it directly into the button's handler.